# missing data firebase sync to bigquery sandbox

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, sandbox

I use Bigquery Sandbox and export raw event data from Google Analytics to Bigquery. But The number of events 2 places are different.Bigquery much less Google Analytics.

My number of events per day usually ranges from 1 to 200 thousand events meanwhile GA usually ranges 7-10 million evets day. And The storage space I have left is 6.97/10 GB.

Comment: Can you please clarify how much data you are exporting from GA to Bigquery Sandbox ,BigQuery Sandbox has some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limitations).You need to check how much active storage you have used by following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#get_information_about_tables).Also if you are exporting data older than 60 days it will not be stored in BQ tables as per the limitations.

Comment: I know BigQuery are limited to 1 million events per day. But my number of events per day   usually ranges from 1 to 200 thousand events meanwhile GA usually ranges 7-10 million evets day.

Comment: You are referring to the GA to BQ event limitation. But `Bigquery sandbox` limitations are different from that.BigQuery sandbox has `storage `[limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limitations) and a default table `expiration time`. Can you check how much space you have left?In general there should not be any data mismatch after exporting the data.
Also can you edit the question and give more insights to how much data discrepancies you are having after exporting , and how much data you are exporting at a single time (min  & max timestamp of event data).

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew. But i don't think so. The storage space I have left is 6.97/10 GB free.

Comment: Can you check if the missing data  is due to [expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limitations) as the default partition expiration is set to 60 days. Any  data ,tables, views, or partitions in partitioned tables automatically expire after 60 days in the sandbox environment.